# JSON Post and Decode array to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, json

I'm tring to post an array to PHP file using JSON. It does not work. The problem is nothing happens. If I decomment datatype:"json" then I get the alert (but without data).

This is my jquery code

```
var arr = new Array();
arr.push('1','Brussels|25');
arr.push('2','Antwerp|40');
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  url: "jsondecode.php",
  data: JSON.stringify(arr),
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data){alert(data);},
  failure: function(errMsg) {
    alert(errMsg);
  }
});
```

And this is my PHP code (jsondecode.php);

```
 <?php
 $array = json_decode($_POST["arr"]);
 foreach($array as $el){
    $el_array=explode('|',$el);
    echo"City=".$el_array[0]." And Age = ".$el_array[1]."";
 }

 ?>
```

Does somebody know a useful tutorial on this?

Comment: What does "does not work" mean exactly?

Comment: What do you mean with "does not work"?

Comment: Nothing happens. If I uncomment dataType:"json", I get the alert but without the data

Answer (score 4):

You have to post the data in this format to retrieve like `$_POST["arr"]`

```
data: { arr : JSON.stringify(arr) },
```

Comment: I did now but $_POST["arr"] is still empty

Comment: @MichaelV Check in console what data is sending to `jsondecode.php`.

Comment: Indeed, unless I delete the dataType:'json' line no data is sent

Comment: @MichaelV yes you have to delete this line because you are receiving data in text format not in JSON format, `dataType:'json'` is used to get the response in JSON format.

Answer (score 3):

What the heck are you trying? 
It looks as if you are trying to put key-value-pairs to the JavaScript-Array with `arr.push('1', 'Brussels|25');` expecting an array containing "Brussels|25" under the key "1" - but watch out, you are creating this array: `["1", "Brussels|25", "2", "Antwerp|40"]`.

If you want to send json, send json-data:

```
var arr= [{  
    "city" : "Brussels",  
    "age" : 25  
},{  
    "city" : "Antwerp",  
    "age" : 40  
}];
```

then your ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "jsondecode.php",
   data: {arr: JSON.stringify(arr)},
   success: function(data){
        console.log("success:",data);},
   failure: function(errMsg) {
        console.error("error:",errMsg);
   }
});
```

So you don't need to explode the data server-sided.

The server-sided script:

```
<?php
$data = json_decode($_POST["arr"]);
// will echo the JSON.stringified - string:
echo $_POST["arr"];
// will echo the json_decode'd object
var_dump($data);
//traversing the whole object and accessing properties:
foreach($data as $cityObject){
    echo "City: " . $cityObject->city . ", Age: " . $cityObject->age . "<br/>";
}
?>
```

Hope, this helps you now.

@edit: By the way, use `console.log()` or `console.error()` instead of alert. Alert will cause scripts to pause until you click on ok and you cannot see objects in an alert.

@2nd edit: the script is now tested, I removed unnecessary code and added the server-sided code

Comment: OK I used this code I just changed  data: {arr: JSON.stringify(arr)}, to data{:jsonarry: JSON.stringify(arr},
 but still it doesn't work, nothing is written to the console logo When I deleted the data Type: "json" line I get a success response (but no data)

Comment: Have you adjusted your php-script to your change? Try echoing something in the jsondecode.php - file to be sure, that you are loading the correct script and it definitely echoes something.

Comment: I put following in the php script  echo"postarr=".$_POST["jsonarray"];   in console I only see the message 'sucess: postarr=' so without the data

Comment: This shows you, that there is no "jsonarray" - key in $_POST. Try a `var_dump($_POST);` in your php script.

Comment: I get an empty array as response "success: array(0) {
}"

Comment: I adjusted the description and put server-sided code on it, try it now, it shall work this way. Remember, that this example is quite useless because you are sending stuff to the server end echoing this stuff right into the console :).

Answer (score 1):

Replace :

```
$array = json_decode($_POST["arr"]);
```

By:

```
 $array = json_decode($_POST["arr"], true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me:

JS:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "jsondecode.php",
    data: JSON.stringify({"1": "Brussels", "2": "Antwerp"}),
    success: function(data){alert(data);},
    failure: function(errMsg) {
        alert(errMsg);
    }
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$p = file_get_contents('php://input');
$x = json_decode($p, true);
echo $x["1"];
?>
```